# My Users datas are coming in html but html page does not show users data

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

İ trying to do when some one open users page Person will see the users details but this html page is not working like this.Users details are coming in database to html page like firstname,id or email but when i tring to see these datas i cannot see

i getting like this picture
[image]

**but i wanna see like this**[image]

**this are my html codes**

```
<div *ngIf="dataLoaded==false" class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
  <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>

 


<table *ngIf="dataLoaded==true" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Adı</th>
      <th scope="col">Soyadı</th>
       
       
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users ;">
      
      <td>{{ user.Email }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.Id }}</td> 
      <td>{{ user.FirstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.LastName }}</td>
      
     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
   
  


</table>
```

**this are my typescript codes**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
 import { Users } from "src/app/models/Users";
import { AuthService } from "src/app/services/auth.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
 
 

 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Users   ;
  users : Users[] = []
  dataLoaded = false;
 

  constructor(private authservice: AuthService,
    private activatedRoute :ActivatedRoute, private toastrService:ToastrService
   ) {}

    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
      if(params["Id"]){
        this.GetUserById(params["Id"])
      }else{
        this.getusers()
      }
    })
}



  getusers() {
    this.authservice.getusers().subscribe(response=>{
      this.users = response.data
      console.log(this.users)
      this.dataLoaded = true;
    })   
  }

  GetUserById(Id:number) {
    this.authservice.GetUserById(Id).subscribe(response=>{
      this.user= response.data
      this.dataLoaded = true;
      console.log(this.users)
 
    })   
  }
```

}

**this is my console log**

```
[webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled. index.js:551
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: 3002, firstName: "striasd", lastName: "stringwww", … }
​​
email: "old@old.com"
​​
firstName: "striasd"
​​
id: 3002



lastName: "stringwww"


 ​​
status: true
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​

1: Object { id: 4002, firstName: "stringq", lastName: "stringq", … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

this is my html console image

[image]

**So what should i do or what is my fault**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using capital letters for rendering the data but your data parameter is small letters, I hope this is the issue.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users ;">
     
     <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.id }}</td> 
     <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: because ı using in database like this is it wrong?

Comment: yes use the same parameters as database.

Comment: yes you are right  need small letters but i dont understand one thing in my database they are big letters why happend like that

Comment: It depends on you when you inserted the values in the database you can use whatever you like small letters or capital but you have to use the same database parameters in your loop.

Comment: i understand it this rule but can it be change ?

Comment: change what database parameters?

Comment: yes database parameters but i understand now thank your time